# Providing unique id to about:blank like about:blank?id=144

Tags: iframe

I am creating a iframe with about:blank?id=uniqueId, and writing the content later into the iframe by accessing its content window. This is not working in Firefox as the iframe window is not accessible. This is working fine with just passing about:blank. Is there a way I can pass an Id to the about:blank src without have permissions issues in Firefox.